# Call Oracle Package from Jasper report Having Multiple Cursors

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, jasper-reports, package

I have a Package In Oracle Which Spools Customer Information. The Package is like:

**EDIT**

```
create or replace
PACKAGE        mfi_statement_spool
AS
   PROCEDURE mfi_main_spool (fromdate IN DATE, todate IN DATE,c1 out SYS_REFCURSOR,c2 out SYS_REFCURSOR);

   FUNCTION mfi_cust_details (vforacid IN VARCHAR2)
      RETURN VARCHAR2;

   FUNCTION mfi_citycountry (vcountrycode IN VARCHAR2, vcitycode IN VARCHAR2)
      RETURN VARCHAR2;
END mfi_statement_spool;
    /
```

I need to use the Main_Spool Procedure Which I declared this way:

**EDIT FULL PACKAGE BODY**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE BODY TBAADM.mfi_statement_spool
AS
  -- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
PROCEDURE mfi_main_spool(
    fromdate DATE,
    todate   DATE,
    c1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
    c2 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
  cramount  NUMBER;
  dramount  NUMBER;
  countcr   NUMBER;
  countdr   NUMBER;
  srl_num   NUMBER;
  ledgerbal NUMBER;
  c1 SYS_REFCURSOR;
  c2 SYS_REFCURSOR;
  opbal             NUMBER;
  vdocremarks       VARCHAR2 (100);
  vremarkscorporate VARCHAR2 (100);
  vremarksretail    VARCHAR2 (100);
  remarks           VARCHAR2 (100);
  endbal            NUMBER;
  curamount         NUMBER;
  totaltrans        NUMBER;
  sumtrans          NUMBER;
  vtranamt          VARCHAR2 (50);
  state1            VARCHAR2 (600);
  rnum              NUMBER;
  state2            VARCHAR2 (600);
  state3            VARCHAR2 (600);
  fuunclamt         NUMBER;
  state4            VARCHAR2 (600);
  balancebf         VARCHAR2 (50);
  ebal              VARCHAR2 (50);
  lbal              VARCHAR2 (50);
  vinstrnumcheck    VARCHAR2 (15);
  vinstrnum         VARCHAR2 (50);
  vpaart            VARCHAR2 (50);
  wfile_handle UTL_FILE.file_type;
  filename VARCHAR2(100);
  CURSOR c1
  IS
    SELECT foracid,
      acct_name,
      addr_1,
      addr_2,
      sol_desc,
      city_code,
      gam.FUTURE_UN_CLR_BAL_AMT
    FROM tbaadm.gam,
      tbaadm.sol
    WHERE gam.sol_id   = sol.sol_id
    AND schm_type     IN ('CAA','ODA','LAA')
    AND schm_code NOT IN ('CTSTF');
  CURSOR c2 (vforacid VARCHAR2)
  IS
    SELECT TRIM (foracid),
      tran_amt,
      part_tran_type,
      acct_name,
      gam.cust_id,
      clr_bal_amt,
      gam.acid,
      un_clr_bal_amt,
      acct_crncy_code,
      tran_date,
      htd.value_date,
      htd.instrmnt_num,
      htd.tran_particular
    FROM tbaadm.gam,
      tbaadm.htd
    WHERE gam.acid     = htd.acid
    AND foracid        = vforacid
    AND tran_date     >= fromdate
    AND tran_date     <= todate
    AND pstd_flg       = 'Y'
    AND htd.del_flg   != 'Y'
    AND acct_cls_flg  != 'Y'
    AND schm_type     IN ('CAA','ODA','LAA')
    AND schm_code NOT IN ('CTSTF')
    ORDER BY foracid,
      htd.pstd_date ;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN c1
  LOOP
    rnum         := 0;
    filename     := 'statement_' || TO_CHAR(i.foracid) || '.TXT';
    wfile_handle := UTL_FILE.fopen ('DIR_TEMP', filename, 'W', 32767);
    BEGIN
      SELECT NVL (SUM (tran_date_bal), 0)
      INTO opbal
      FROM tbaadm.gam,
        tbaadm.eab
      WHERE gam.acid  = eab.acid
      AND gam.foracid = i.foracid
      AND eod_date    =
        (SELECT MAX(eod_date)
        FROM tbaadm.eab
        WHERE eod_date < fromdate
        AND acid      IN
          (SELECT acid FROM tbaadm.gam WHERE foracid=i.foracid
          )
        );
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      opbal := 0;
    END;
    BEGIN
      IF opbal < 0 THEN
        SELECT REPLACE(concat(TO_CHAR(opbal,'9999999990D99') ,' DR'),'-')
        INTO balancebf
        FROM dual;
      ELSE
        SELECT concat(TO_CHAR(opbal,'9999999990D99') ,' CR') INTO balancebf FROM dual;
      END IF;
    END;
    BEGIN
      SELECT NVL (SUM (DECODE (part_tran_type, 'D', -1 * tran_amt, tran_amt ) ), 0 )
      INTO sumtrans
      FROM tbaadm.htd
      WHERE acid =
        (SELECT acid FROM tbaadm.gam WHERE foracid = i.foracid
        )
      AND pstd_flg   = 'Y'
      AND del_flg   != 'Y'
      AND tran_date >= fromdate
      AND tran_date <= todate;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      sumtrans := 0;
    END;
    endbal := sumtrans + opbal;
    BEGIN
      IF endbal < 0 THEN
        SELECT REPLACE(concat(TO_CHAR(endbal,'9999999990D99') ,' DR'),'-')
        INTO ebal
        FROM dual;
      ELSE
        SELECT concat(TO_CHAR(endbal,'9999999990D99') ,' CR') INTO ebal FROM dual;
      END IF;
    END;
    BEGIN
      SELECT NVL (SUM (DECODE (part_tran_type, 'D', 1, 0)), 0),
        NVL (SUM (DECODE (part_tran_type, 'C', 1, 0)), 0)
      INTO countdr,
        countcr
      FROM tbaadm.htd
      WHERE acid IN
        (SELECT acid FROM tbaadm.gam WHERE foracid = i.foracid
        )
      AND tran_date >= fromdate
      AND tran_date <= todate
      AND pstd_flg   = 'Y'
      AND del_flg   != 'Y';
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      countcr := 0;
      countdr := 0;
    END;
    totaltrans := countcr + countdr;
    FOR j                IN c2 (i.foracid)
    LOOP
      rnum := rnum + 1;
      SELECT TO_CHAR (DECODE (j.part_tran_type, 'C', j.tran_amt, '0.00'),'9999999990D99')
        || '|'
        || TO_CHAR (DECODE (j.part_tran_type, 'D', j.tran_amt, '0.00'),'9999999990D99')
      INTO vtranamt
      FROM DUAL;
      SELECT DECODE (j.part_tran_type, 'D', -1 * j.tran_amt, j.tran_amt)
      INTO curamount
      FROM DUAL;
      opbal   := opbal + curamount;
      IF opbal < 0 THEN
        SELECT REPLACE(concat(TO_CHAR(opbal,'9999999990D99') ,' DR'),'-')
        INTO lbal
        FROM dual;
      ELSE
        SELECT concat(TO_CHAR(opbal,'9999999990D99') ,' CR') INTO lbal FROM dual;
      END IF;
      BEGIN
        BEGIN
          SELECT DISTINCT purgeremarks
          INTO vremarksretail
          FROM crmuser.accounts
          WHERE orgkey =
            (SELECT cif_id FROM tbaadm.cmg WHERE cmg.cust_id =j.cust_id
            )
          AND rownum < 2;
        EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
          vremarksretail := NULL;
        END;
        IF (vremarksretail IS NULL) THEN
          BEGIN
            SELECT DISTINCT remarks
            INTO vremarkscorporate
            FROM crmuser.corporate
            WHERE corp_key =
              (SELECT cif_id FROM tbaadm.cmg WHERE cmg.cust_id =j.cust_id
              )
            AND rownum < 2;
          EXCEPTION
          WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            vremarkscorporate := NULL;
          END;
          remarks := vremarkscorporate;
        ELSE
          remarks := vremarksretail;
        END IF;
      END;
      BEGIN
        SELECT DISTINCT docremarks
        INTO vdocremarks
        FROM crmuser.entitydocument
        WHERE core_cust_id = j.cust_id
        AND rownum         < 2;
      EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        vdocremarks := NULL;
      END;
      BEGIN
        SELECT SUBSTR (j.tran_particular, 1, 7) INTO vinstrnumcheck FROM DUAL;
      EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        vinstrnumcheck := NULL;
      END;
      IF (vinstrnumcheck = 'BY INST') THEN
        vpaart          := 'OUTWARD CLEARING KES';
      ELSE
        vpaart := j.tran_particular;
      END IF;
      IF (vinstrnumcheck = 'BY INST') THEN
        SELECT SUBSTR (j.tran_particular, 8, (INSTR (j.tran_particular, ':') - 8) )
        INTO vinstrnum
        FROM DUAL;
      ELSE
        vinstrnum := j.instrmnt_num;
      END IF;
      BEGIN
        SELECT FUTURE_UN_CLR_BAL_AMT
        INTO fuunclamt
        FROM tbaadm.gam g
        WHERE g.foracid=i.foracid;
      END;
      BEGIN
        UTL_FILE.put_line (wfile_handle, rnum || '|' || i.foracid || '|' || j.acct_crncy_code || '|' || j.tran_date || '|' || j.value_date || '|' || vinstrnum || '|' || vpaart || '|' || vtranamt || '|' || lbal || '|' || j.acct_name || '|' || mfi_cust_details (i.foracid) || '|' || ebal || '|' || countdr || '|' || countcr || '|' || j.un_clr_bal_amt || '|' || balancebf || '|' || fromdate || '|' || todate || '|' || todate || '|' || remarks || '|' || vdocremarks || '|' || fuunclamt );
      END;
    END LOOP;
    rnum := rnum - 1;
    UTL_FILE.fclose (wfile_handle);
  END LOOP;
END mfi_main_spool;
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FUNCTION mfi_cust_details(
    vforacid VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  vcustdetails VARCHAR2 (300);
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    SELECT a.cust_title_code
      || '|'
      || a.cust_id
      || '|'
      || b.address_line1
      || '|'
      || b.address_line2
      || '|'
      || mfi_citycountry (b.country, b.city)
      || '|'
      || b.zip
    INTO vcustdetails
    FROM tbaadm.cmg a,
      crmuser.address b
    WHERE TRIM (a.cif_id)          = TRIM (b.orgkey)
    AND UPPER (b.addresscategory) IN ('MAILING', 'REGISTERED')
    AND cust_id                   IN
      (SELECT cust_id FROM gam WHERE foracid = vforacid
      );
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    vcustdetails := NULL || '|' || NULL || '|' || NULL || '|' || NULL || '|' || NULL || '|' || NULL || '|' || NULL;
  END;
  RETURN vcustdetails;
END mfi_cust_details;
FUNCTION mfi_citycountry(
    vcountrycode VARCHAR2,
    vcitycode    VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  vcountry      VARCHAR2 (50);
  vcity         VARCHAR2 (50);
  vcity_country VARCHAR2 (100);
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    SELECT ref_desc
    INTO vcountry
    FROM tbaadm.rct
    WHERE ref_rec_type = '03'
    AND ref_code       = vcountrycode;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    vcountry := NULL;
  END;
  BEGIN
    SELECT ref_desc
    INTO vcity
    FROM tbaadm.rct
    WHERE ref_rec_type = '01'
    AND ref_code       = vcitycode;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    vcity := NULL;
  END;
  vcity_country := vcity || '|' || vcountry;
  RETURN vcity_country;
END mfi_citycountry;
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------
END mfi_statement_spool;
/
```

**EDIT: THE ERROR IS STILL THERE**

I have Two Cursors In the Procedure Above, Cursor 1 And Cursor Two. I have tried to add the Cursors into the declarations like:

```
...PROCEDURE mfi_main_spool (fromdate DATE, todate DATE,c1 out SYS_REFCURSOR,c2 out SYS_REFCURSOR).....
```

So that it I can use it with Jasper but the package Body does Not Compile with the Following Error:

```
PLS-00323: subprogram or cursor 'MFI_MAIN_SPOOL' is declared in a package specification and must be defined in the package body
```

Is there Something I am not doing Correctly?

Comment: Did you define `c1` and `c2` in your package body? They have to be declared as normal variables as they are `OUT`-parameters?

Comment: Yes I have Declared then as SYS_REFCURSOR. Could this be the Mistake?

Comment: No, SYS_REFCURSOR should be fine. I'll post a complete overview over your package and package body. If yours looks like that, you may have to post more code as the error doesn't seem to be in the part you have posted so far.

Comment: See I have Posted the Entire Code. Full Package Body.

Comment: If you have a `SYS_REFURCURSOR` you can't use it with `CURSOR c1 is ....`, you have to do the following: `OPEN c1 for SELECT...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update your package specification first:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE mfi_statement_spool
AS
   PROCEDURE mfi_main_spool (fromdate IN DATE, todate IN DATE,c1 out SYS_REFCURSOR,c2 out SYS_REFCURSOR);

   FUNCTION mfi_cust_details (vforacid IN VARCHAR2)
      RETURN VARCHAR2;

   FUNCTION mfi_citycountry (vcountrycode IN VARCHAR2, vcitycode IN VARCHAR2)
      RETURN VARCHAR2;
END mfi_statement_spool;
/
```

After that update your package body with the new parameters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY mfi_statement_spool
AS
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   PROCEDURE mfi_main_spool (fromdate DATE, todate DATE, c1 out SYS_REFCURSOR,c2 out SYS_REFCURSOR)
   AS
      cramount            NUMBER;
      dramount            NUMBER;
   BEGIN
     OPEN c1 for
       SELECT foracid,
         acct_name,
         addr_1,
         addr_2,
         sol_desc,
         city_code,
         gam.FUTURE_UN_CLR_BAL_AMT
       FROM tbaadm.gam,
         tbaadm.sol
       WHERE gam.sol_id   = sol.sol_id
         AND schm_type     IN ('CAA','ODA','LAA')
         AND schm_code NOT IN ('CTSTF');
     -- handle c2 the same way...
     LOOP
       FETCH c1 into v_foracid, v_acct_name, v_addr_1, ...;
       EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
       -- do something with your variables here
     END LOOP;
     CLOSE c1;
     -- same for c2 again...
   END mfi_main_spool;

   FUNCTION mfi_cust_details (vforacid IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
   BEGIN
 NULL;
     -- do something here
   END mfi_cust_details;

   FUNCTION mfi_citycountry (vcountrycode IN VARCHAR2, vcitycode IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
   BEGIN
 NULL;
     -- do something here
   END mfi_citycountry;
    END;
         /
```

**This way it's compiling fine for me.**

For every procedure that is defined in your package specification, you have to have one procedure in your package body that is defined the same way, meaning it has the same name, expects the same parameters and has the same returntype if it's a function, etc.
But you can have more *hidden* procedures and functions in your body that can't be accessed from outside the package. They don't have to be defined in the package specification.

For a guide on `SYS_REFCURSOR` see here:
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets.php or here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html

Comment: But That is exactly What I have tried and the Error Is still There. See My Updated question for the details.

Comment: @stanley there is no update to your question. Pls update your package specification, not only your procedure declaration

Comment: @stanley I updated my answer to make it more clear what I mean

Comment: Check it is there. I have Changed Both the package and the Package Body but the error is still there

Comment: @stanley updated it again. It's working fine for me this way.

Comment: I have Posted the Full Package Body Anything out of this? I am trying Your example without the Actions

Comment: Yes yours Is Compiling. I cannot Site out the Problem In Mine

Comment: I think your problem is with your usage of `SYS_REFCURSOR`. See my update and the links for more information

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42789/discussion-between-armunin-and-stanley)

Answer (score 0):

Hi
It seems that the procedure signature in 
package specification is different from the package body.
These two should match exactly. You can try like this.
It should work. Thanks

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TBAADM.mfi_statement_spool
AS
   PROCEDURE mfi_main_spool (fromdate IN DATE, 
todate IN DATE,
c1 out SYS_REFCURSOR,
c2 out SYS_REFCURSOR);

   FUNCTION mfi_cust_details (vforacid IN VARCHAR2)
      RETURN VARCHAR2;

   FUNCTION mfi_citycountry (vcountrycode IN VARCHAR2, vcitycode IN VARCHAR2)
      RETURN VARCHAR2;
END mfi_statement_spool;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TBAADM.mfi_statement_spool
AS
   PROCEDURE mfi_main_spool (fromdate DATE, todate DATE)
   AS 
Begin
/* Stuff you want to do */
end mfi_main_spool;
/* definition of other procedures and function. */
end mfi_statement_spool;
```

Comment: From What I get Is that the Package has the Cursor declaration and the Body does not but this is What Is giving me `Error(3,14): PLS-00323: subprogram or cursor 'MFI_MAIN_SPOOL' is declared in a package specification and must be defined in the package body`